# Why desn't my Pom file work when adding Cucumber: 'cucumber-spring' and 'cucumber-guice'?

Tags: maven

Why dosnt my Pom file work when adding Cucumber: 'cucumber-spring' and 'cucumber-guice'?

My Cucumber project setup works with the following dependencies:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <!--<executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javac.exe</executable> -->
                    <executable>${env.JAVA_HOME}\bin\javac.exe</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>Framework.utilities.SendEmailFile</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <!-- <configuration> <suiteXmlFiles> <suiteXmlFile>ncc.xml</suiteXmlFile> 
                    </suiteXmlFiles> <testErrorIgnore>false</testErrorIgnore> <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore> 
                    </configuration> -->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Adding the following dependencies stops my project from working:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-guice</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can add only one of the DI jars in your classpath. You are trying to include 3 of them. Need to choose between pico, guice or spring

Answer (score 1):

it is dependency version issue, you should try lower version of cucumber-spring. use 1.2.4 version or lower version... and update maven project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-guice</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, im afraid it still dosnt work when lowering the version number :/

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber exposes an extension mechanism for DI frameworks called `cucumber.api.java.ObjectFactory`.

If you look at the code of the associated loader method `cucumber.runtime.java.ObjectFactoryLoader#loadObjectFactory` you will see that it calls `cucumber.runtime.Reflections#instantiateExactlyOneSubclass` which throws either `TooManyInstancesException` or `NoInstancesException`.

It is clear that it needs **zero or one public class implementing `ObjectFactory`** and being in the package `cucumber.runtime`.

- The default one is `cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory`, loaded only if `NoInstancesException` is thrown (not found through scanning because it is package protected)
- **cucumber-spring** comes with `cucumber.runtime.java.spring.SpringFactory`
- etc.

In your case you must choose among available ones (none/default, Picocontainer, Spring, Guice) which one to use to instanciate stepdefs classes.